# Why am I able to pass mutable and immutable reference at the same time?

Tags: rust

As per the rust book, we cannot use a variable as mutable and immutable reference at the same time.

But for some reason when I try to do that with a `u32` type, it does NOT throw any error.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut num = 69;
    do_something(&mut num); // no error
    dont_do_anything(&num); // no error
    println!("{}", num);
}

fn dont_do_anything(num: &u32) {
    println!("{}", num);
}

fn do_something(num: &mut u32)  {
    *num += 1;
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You don't use them at the same time, only doing that is disallowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't passing them at the same time, you're passing them one after the other.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut num = 69;
    // at the following line you start to borrow num mutably
    do_something(&mut num);
    // but the mutable borrow is only used in the line above

    // at the following line you start a shared borrow of num
    dont_do_anything(&num);
    // and you only use the shared borrow in the line above.

    // then you do another shared borrow for `pritnln`
    println!("{}", num);
    // which is used just in the one line again.
}
```

Since no overlaps between any of the borrows occur, none of the borrow rules are broken.
Now let's look at something that would be disallowed:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut num = 69;
    // start mutably borrowing
    let mut_num = &mut num;
    // try to borrow immutably after we started a mutable borrow, but before we stopped using it
    dont_do_anything(&num);
    // use the mutable borrow here
    do_something(mut_num);
}
```

This snippet does use a mutable and an immutable borrow at the same time (the line where we call `dont_do_anything`) and thus the compiler yells at us:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `num` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:6:22
  |
4 |     let mut_num = &mut num;
  |                   -------- mutable borrow occurs here
5 |     // try to borrow immutably after we started a mutable borrow, but before we stopped using it
6 |     dont_do_anything(&num);
  |                      ^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
7 |     // use the mutable borrow here
8 |     do_something(mut_num);
  |                  ------- mutable borrow later used here
```